# JavaScript - Accessing Firebase data by key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase data structure]

I'm using React with Firebase.
I want to retrieve a data called "Phone". Is there any way to retrieve it?
When i console.log, i only get "User"

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('Users');
  ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  let key = snapshot.child(this.state.username).val();; 
  console.log(key);
});
```

Comment: You don't "call" data/fields/variables/properties. You call functions/methods/constructors. You  "access" or "read" (or "write") them.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to get the title:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('Users');
ref.child(this.state.username).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val().title);
});
```

If you're new to Firebase, I recommend taking the [Firebase codelab for web developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/), which covers this and many other topics.